# lazy loader in laravel and vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

hello guys i m new to vue so don't know why this function not working. i m using laravel 5.5 and vue 2.5. in vue router  i m try to implement lazy loading router here is my code

```
const Full = () => import('../containers/Full')
```

when i use this line of code it throw error like  Unexpected token.
but if i use like this it work properly

```
import Full from '../containers/Full';
```

i had created a file .babelrc and include below things

```
{
"plugins": ["dynamic-import-webpack"]
  }
```

but still same error and i does lots of google but haven't fine any proper solution what i m missing.